# How to invite a user with devise_invitable directly from within Rails_Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin, devise-invitable

I have a `Rails 5` application with a `Rails_Admi`n installation. I work with a `AdminUser model` and a `User model`, both based on `Devise`.

I've also installed `devise_invitable` on the User model and used the AdminUser model for the `invited_by` reference.

I would like to add a `'invite user'` action to the users collection (next to `'Add new'`) within `Rails_Admin`. I tried to figure out how to create a `custom action`, but I'm stuck.

Any ideas  how I can solve this?

Comment: I used to struggle with this so i created this gist, so you know where to put what and how to name it
https://gist.github.com/grillermo/3570369b12e6b4587672f33fc84a8662
When creating a rails admin action

Comment: Thanks @GuillermoSiliceo!